# Custom html video player with bugs

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, controls

I was wandering if someone could help me to correct two little problems on Custom HTML5 Video.

The first problem is that if you load the web site for the first time, everything is fine but if you refresh the page and start playing the video, you will notice that the progress bar will be full.

The second problem is that if you click the button to make the video fullscreen then press space, it will close the video. How can i provent it ?

Here is a link to the github project : https://github.com/Freshman-tech/custom-html5-video
Here is the website http://custom-html5-video.surge.sh

I have tried a lot of things without succes, I'm bad at html

Comment: Please include the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code in the question itself, rather than expecting us to go explore github in order to help. As for linking us to the site, please look at the advice over on [Meta]: "*[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/82548)*" spoiler: no, because you might correct the problem rendering the link useless, and the question meaningless, for future visitors. It would also be worth taking the [tour], and reading the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Answer (score 0):

1/ the red progress bar appears to indicate how much of the video is loaded/buffered

2/ pressing the space button is the equivalent in most browsers of clicking the currently selected link/button, so if you, for instance, click `play` then press `f` to go to fullscreen mode and hit `space` it will re-click the play button rather than minimising. You might be able to trap the space button and re-use if for play/pause (or similar) when in fullscreen mode